# bash prompt change after user default directory change

Tags: bash, user-accounts, centos-6, etcpasswd

There is something I am not understanding.  I have used the method found here about changing user default directory using vipw /etc/passwd

However once I go into this file and change a user default dir setting their bash prompt changes to, from my machine from ex. "[root@directory ~]#" to "bash-4.1$"

Now if I try to change the global bash prompt $PS1 the user with change dir having bash-4.1$ cannot see the custom prompt.

What is this behavior?

Comment: I believe you are mistaken about what the directory named in /etc/passwd actually is. It's the user's home directory; it's not a "default directory", except by convention and extension because it's a directory that is *supposedly* writable by the user, and relatively private. (Remember Linux is a multi-user system by design.) If the named home directory doesn't exist, or if it does exist but the permissions don't grant the user read/write/execute permissions, all sorts of things will break. I have a strong feeling you are seeing one of those things breaking.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks for the reply.  Actually you're right, when I changed the directory, whatever I changed it to I realized that there were permission problems.  So this means only because there was a permission problem, or whatever else it could be, this is why I'm seeing this weird bash-4.1?  obviously I won't be lazy and test this but since I'm typing away here...

Comment: @GuySt-Louis It is indeed a permission problem. The prompt changes because bash can not find a readable `.bash_profile` or the like (which is normally located in your home directory as dictated by `/etc/passwd` from which it can read your prompt settings, so it reverts to defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You changed your home directory, but you probably left the files in the old directory.

When `bash` is invoked it reads and executes some files, some of them in your home directory (for example `~/.profile`).

Since you changed your home directory it doesn't find them. So any configurations you find in those files (like your prompt) won't get applied to your `bash`.

Comment: ill take a look at this too

Comment: do you know all the files that need to be transferred over to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a bash user and I use another OS. Your bash manpage should have a list of files it uses (probably near the end of the manpage). Also like inside those files - maybe those files call other files.